# FilterQueryProvider not updating ListView

Tags: android

Trying to use the FilterQueryProvider function to update the contents of a ListView, as characters are entered into the filter, my runQuery function does get called, and a new cursor with filtered content is returned, but the ListView does not update to show the new contents. The docs state that after runQuery returns, changeCursor is called. Isn't this enough to update the ListView display? My code to set up the filter is:

```
    mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(curs);
    mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new ItemFilter());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And my filter class is simply:

```
class ItemFilter implements FilterQueryProvider {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence filter) {
        return getNewCursor(filter);
    }
}
```

The cursor from getNewCursor does correctly fetch a subset of the rows. Have I missed something in getting the ListView to update?

Comment: How are you doing the filtering? Are you calling runQueryOnBackgroundThread(someFilterConstraint)?